# Unityをバージョンアップしたら　webGLビルドできなくなってしまいました。

Tags: unity3d, webgl

以前：　version 2019.3
アップデート：　version 2021.2

以前はunity WebGLで普通にビルドできていましたが
unityのバージョンアップを行うと下記エラーが出てくるようになりました。

UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 70264: illegal multibyte sequence
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

検索をかけてみてもpythonに関すること等や文字コードの違い？
のような内容記事があったのですが
具体的にどう直せばよいのかわからず。
教えて頂けると有難いです。

Comment: 例えば上手くいかないプロジェクト全体を何処かにアップロードして、そこへの紹介リンクを貼るとか？ それが大きすぎるとか隠したい情報があるなら、こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に問題が再現できる最小限のプロジェクトを作成して提示するとかしてみたらどうでしょう？ [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) そうしたものを作る過程で自分自身で原因を見つけられる場合もあるでしょう。

Comment: ちなみにこちら [Upgrading to Unity 2021.2](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/UpgradeGuide20212.html) の **WebGL: Updated Emscripten to 2.0.19** に`This upgraded the native code object file format, and therefore requires recompiling all native code plugins (C/C++ code plugins) in a project.`とあるので、何かそうした外部モジュール/データや参照するものがあるなら、それらを更新してみてはどうでしょう？